# Running total with a slicer in Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to find the running total by month, it worked using the following measure but only without using a slicer for the category "BLK":

```
With Date =  VAR MaxDate =
    MAX ( 'Calendar Table'[Date] ) RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Injuries'[Total] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Injuries'[Classification] ),
            'Injuries'[Classification] = "FAC"
        ),
        FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( 'Calendar Table' ), 'Calendar Table'[Date] <= MaxDate)
    )+0
```

The result was only accurate when I don't apply the Category slicer "BLK", I tried a different measure:

```
With BLK =  CALCULATE(  SUM('Oxy Oman Personal Injuries'[Total]),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Injuries'[Classification] ),
            'Injuries'[Classification] = "FAC"
        ),  ALLSELECTED('Blocks'[BLK]) )+0
```

The above gave me something similar to the actual data, it did not sum up the numbers.. at least it gave me the correct total of a the category selected = 5 while the first measure gave the total wrong = 4.

Here is a screenshot of the results for both measures with and without a slicer:

Without BLK slicer:(With Data gave me what I wanted)

[image]

Using one Category in the BLK Slicer:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Are 'Blocks' and 'Injuries' linked? What is the reason for  ALLSELECTED('Blocks'[BLK]) )? Why do you want to avoid current context?

Comment: Yes, BLK column is linked in both tables. Blocks table have the BLK and ID column, in Injuries table BLK column linked with BLK column in in Blocks table.

Comment: What is wrong with 'With Date' measure? I cant get the point why you use `ALLSELECTED ( 'Calendar Table' )` instead of `ALL ( 'Calendar Table' ) ` , but the rest seems workable, if your tables are linked

Comment: So, in general `With Date` shows' you running total. What's wrong with it?

Comment: When I use a slicer for a category it gives me wrong values. it only works when I am not using any slicer.

Comment: on the bottom one what values should be for cumulative?